# How to use the Magnus Series Convergence Test for complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have a two by two functional complex matrix $A$ belonging to the Magnus differential equation
\begin{align}
Y'(x)=A(x)Y(x)
\end{align}
I read from wiki that a convergence test for real $A$ can be constructed as follows
\begin{align}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} ||A(x)||_2 dx < \pi 
\end{align}
where I assume for a two by two matrix
\begin{align}
||A(x)||_2
=
\sqrt{A_{11}^2+A_{21}^2+A_{12}^2+A_{22}^2}
\end{align}
However what does one use for a convergence test if $A(x)$ is complex?

Comment: There's some ambiguity in notation with matrices regarding $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{2}$. Sometimes it denotes the Frobenius norm, other times the maximum eigenvalue modulus. Can you clear this confusion up?

Comment: what about using $\lvert A \lvert^2 = \bar A^T A,$  where $bar A$ is the complex conjugate of $A.$

Comment: @NickThompson That's my problem. I do not know what $||\cdot||_2$ is. It would make sense to me if it was the maximum absolute valued eigenvalue, but I cannot find a paper that confirms this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5488v1.pdf) that your identification of $\left\|\cdot\right\|_{2}$ with the Frobenius norm is incorrect, as the convergence criteria holds even for infinite-dimensional Banach algebras, and there is no extension of the Frobenius norms to infinite dimensional spaces. Therefore, the proper interpretation is the maximum eigenvalue modulus. (See equation 67 of the link.)

Comment: Thanks. What happens if two eigenvalues are equal maximum modules, but of opposing sign? Does equation 67 still hold, or is there a different measure required?

Comment: If the modulus of the eigenvalues are equal but the eigenvalues have opposing sign, there is no problem, the relation still holds.

Comment: I posted a related question, of which I believe you might be able to provide some insight. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100492/does-the-magnus-convergence-test-not-hold-for-the-factorization-of-second-order