# Does the magnus convergence test not hold for the factorization of second order differential operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, eigenfunctions, perturbation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}$Given the operator 
\begin{align}
H = V(x)-\partial_x^2
\end{align}
and given an eigenfunction $\phi_0(x)$ such that $H\phi_0=0$ with a zero eigenvalue, I can factor $H$ into
\begin{align}
H = h_+h_-
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
h_{\pm} = 
\dfrac{\phi_0'}{\phi_0} \pm \partial_x
\end{align}
If $H\phi_j=-\lambda_j^2\phi_j$, where $\lambda_j$ is a real constant, then $(h_-h_+)(h_-\phi_j)=-\lambda_j^2(h_-\phi_j)$, thus
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
h_+h_- && 0
\\
0 && h_-h_+
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=
-
\lambda_j^2
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
This leads to the following operator factorization
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && h_+
\\
h_- && 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && h_+
\\
h_- && 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=
(i\lambda_j)(i\lambda_j)
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
from which I assume
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && h_+
\\
h_- && 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=
(i\lambda_j)
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
I rearrange terms for Magnus Series compatibility
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
-(i\lambda_j) && h_+
\\
h_- && -(i\lambda_j)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && -1
\\
1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-(i\lambda_j) && h_+
\\
h_- && -(i\lambda_j)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
-h_- && (i\lambda_j)
\\
-(i\lambda_j) && h_+
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_x-\phi_0'/\phi_0 && (i\lambda_j)
\\
-(i\lambda_j) && \partial_x+\phi_0'/\phi_0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}'
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_0'/\phi_0 && -(i\lambda_j)
\\
(i\lambda_j) && -\phi_0'/\phi_0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_j
\\
h_-\psi_j
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
to setup the Magnus differential equation
\begin{align}
Y'=AY
\end{align}
I discover the maximum modules eigenvalues of $A$ to be
\begin{align}
\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\phi_0'}{\phi_0}\right)^2+(\lambda_j)^2}
\end{align}
and then calculate the range of convergence
\begin{align}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\phi_0'}{\phi_0}\right)^2+(\lambda_j)^2} dx < \pi
\end{align}

However the calculation of the range of convergence quickly broke down for simple forms of $H$. For example
\begin{align}
H = -2\sech(x)^2-\partial_x^2
\end{align}
has a zero eigenfunction $\phi_0=\tanh(x)$ and only one normalizable eigenfunction $\phi_{-1} = \sech(x)/\sqrt{2}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_{-1}=1$. The range of convergence is written
\begin{align}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{\left(\csch(x)\sech(x)\right)^2+(\lambda_j)^2} dx < \pi
\end{align}
where $\phi_0'(x)=\sech^2(x)$. This range of convergence fails when $x$ gets too close to $x=0$, however $\phi_{-1}$ is well behaved around $x=0$. What is wrong with this analysis?

Comment: Can we start with $V(x) := x^2$? I think that would clarify the situation since everyone is familiar with the raising and lowering operators for the quantum harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I tried that as well. Ironically, the ground state is more simpler than the zero state. The zero state appeared functionally similar to the absolute value of x, however that was only one of the two linearly independent solutions. It might be better to factorize H using the ground state instead.

Comment: I just tried for x^2 using the ground state factorization, and I get $\int \sqrt{x^2+\lambda^2} dx$, of which only converges for finite $x$.

Comment: Well, yes, but you are attempting to find the range of $x$'s such that the integral is $< \pi$. But I think you have a bigger problem, namely that $x^2 -\partial_{x}^{2}$ is an unbounded operator.

Comment: This is very strange. It seems I have made an invalid assumption when I used the Magnus Convergence Test. Maybe the operator must be bounded? I believe $H=-2\sech^2(x)-p_x^2$ is bounded, but its factorization is not bounded.

Comment: I would be very surprised if $H$ was bounded, as neither $x^{2} - \partial_{x}^{2}$ nor $-\partial_{x}^2$ is bounded.